# Why is "getElementsByTagName" not finding anything?

Tags: javascript

This seems like it should be pretty basic, and I can't figure out why it isn't working. I have a super simple page so far and I want to select the paragraphs with JS:

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="misc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="first">Just one paragraph.</p>
    <p id="second">Two, actually.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my JS:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(paras.length);
```

I expect the console log to show `2` but I'm seeing `0`. I read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) pretty closely and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Seems to work fine in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0xjhznta/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time you run the script, there are no paragraphs in the document.

Either move the script element so it appears after the paragraphs, or put the code in a function and then call that function later (e.g. when the `load` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) fires).

Comment: The browser parses your html page and finds your script before html body starts to be parsed. To avoid that you can put the script tag at the bottom of the tag `<body>` or execute your JavaScript code after the DOM is loaded. 

    `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // code
    })`

Comment: I feel like a dope but ... duh. Thanks.